# Xamarin Forms listview shows blank item

Tags: listview, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I tried to show data on custom list view. However, it shows a list with nothing inside. Since the blank item still showing in the list view, so i guess the problem lies on `sessionID` and username binding but I cant figure out where is the problem. Some answers said that the binding data must the property instead of field but I have done it.

#### HistoryPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="ble.net.sampleapp.view.HistoryPage"
                 Title="{Binding Title}">
        <AbsoluteLayout>
            <Button StyleClass="Large"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.98,0.3, 0.1"   
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="XProportional,YProportional,WidthProportional, HeightProportional"  
                    Margin="10,5"
                    Text="Refresh"
                    Command="{Binding Refresh}"/>
            <ListView x:Name="HistoryListView"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding HistoryList}"
                      ItemSelected="onItemSelected"
                    SeparatorColor="#aaaaaa"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">


                <ListView.SeparatorVisibility>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="SeparatorVisibility"
                                Android="Default"
                                iOS="Default"
                                WinPhone="Default" />
                </ListView.SeparatorVisibility>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Frame Margin="{StaticResource GridPadding}"
                                 Padding="{StaticResource GridPadding}">

                                <Grid RowSpacing="5">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                                       Text="{Binding sessionID}"
                                       FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                                       Text="{Binding username}"
                                       FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Frame>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentPage>
```

#### HistoryViewModel

```
private ObservableCollection<Features> historyList = new ObservableCollection<Features>();
public ObservableCollection<Features> HistoryList
{
    get { return historyList; }
    set
    {
        historyList = value;
        RaiseCurrentPropertyChanged();
    }
}

//query data from SQL
HistoryList = await sql.GetFeatureItemsAsync(common.getUsername());
```

#### Feature.cs

```
namespace ble.net.sampleapp.func
{
    public class Features
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public string sessionID { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "deviceId")]
        public string deviceID { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "username")]
        public string username { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "startTime")]
        public DateTimeOffset startTime { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "endTime")]
        public DateTimeOffset endTime { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

Where is the problem? How can I show the `sessionID` and `username` properly in the list view?

Comment: I can't see anywhere you are actually loading data into HistoryList

Comment: I am sorry as I forgot to add one more line which used to query SQL. I have edited.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged (INPC) Interface in the Features class.

Abstractly spoken: each element of the observable class has to handle the INPC itself to inform the view about updates for an individual listview cell.

Try this:

```
public class Features : BindableBase
{
    private string _sessionID;
    public string sessionID
    {
        get { return _sessionID; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _sessionID, value); }
    }
}
```

And the INotifyPropertyChanged wrapper: (taken from somewhere on the msdn website)

```
public class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        ///
        /// Multicast event for property change notifications.
        ///
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        ///
        /// Checks if a property already matches a desired value.  Sets the property and
        /// notifies listeners only when necessary.
        ///
        ///Type of the property.
        ///Reference to a property with both getter and setter.
        ///Desired value for the property.
        ///Name of the property used to notify listeners.  This
        /// value is optional and can be provided automatically when invoked from compilers that
        /// support CallerMemberName.
        ///True if the value was changed, false if the existing value matched the
        /// desired value.
        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (object.Equals(storage, value)) return false;

            storage = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        ///
        /// Notifies listeners that a property value has changed.
        ///
        ///Name of the property used to notify listeners.  This
        /// value is optional and can be provided automatically when invoked from compilers
        /// that support .
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

So in the end, let every model, that should update the view, inherit from the bindable base and call the SetProperty(...) in the setter of a property.

Comment: I have done it in view model. Should I do it when declaring the Features class?

Comment: Yes, your features class has to inherit from the INPC interface. The property changed in your viewmodel will only have effect when the observablecollection adds or removes elements.

Comment: is it possible that the problem is the xaml? Because i just found out that even i type the text manually, nothing shows up

Comment: Honestly, this is might indeed be the case, since you actually dont need INPC if the values never change. I'll take one more look at it

Comment: Try removing the margin and padding on the frame and just add one label to the frame and nothing else. Just <Frame> <Labbel Text="am i visible?"/> </Frame>

Comment: Other options: Set a background color to the listview, and another to a listview-cell and see if everything is rendererd correctly. If you have a screenshot, then post it. Try also setting "HasUnevenRows" to true in the listview

Comment: you are correct. The frame causing the problem. Wasting so much time on wrong direction. Thanks!

Comment: Ok very nice! Better check one thing at a time :P

Comment: @SamTew - for the sake of others who find this Q&A, what *exactly* is the change you made that fixed your display? Thanks.